# How do I call a static method within a nested class?

Tags: python-3.x, class, nested, static-methods

I have two classes, one is `Parent`, the other is `Child`.

In the `Child`, I have two static functions, `foo()` and `bar()`.
In `foo()`, I want to call `bar()`.

But since `Child` is nested, I can't call it using the conventional way.

```
Class Parent:

    Class Child:

        @staticmethod
        def foo():
            Child.bar() #Doesn't work

        @staticmethod
        def bar():
             pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 main methods to achieve what you seek:

1. Reference both the `Parent` and `Child` classes like so:

   ```
   class Parent:

       class Child:

           @staticmethod
           def foo():
               Parent.Child.bar()

           @staticmethod
           def bar():
                pass
   ```
2. Use the implicit `__class__` cell, created by the interpreter [***based on lexical scoping***](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object):

   ```
   class Parent:

       class Child:

           @staticmethod
           def foo():
               __class__.bar()

           @staticmethod
           def bar():
               pass
   ```

Both ways are fully viable in Python 3.x.

There are 3 caveats:

1. An over-use of *static methods* is sometimes an indicator of a design flaw, in which case an outer standalone function would be the better choice.
2. None of the methods will work with inheritance. If `Parent.Child` is inherited from, `Parent.Child.bar()` will reference the method of the same old class, while `__class__` will show the same original `Parent.Child` class, as lexical scoping is used.
3. The first method will cause an infinite recursion if certain class decorators are used. Using `__class__` makes sure you reference the true original class, and might help eliminate that problem.

Comment: __class__ seems great! Thanks. Are there any limitations of __class__ vs Parent.Child?

Comment: @Pathfinder there are no limitations or differences that I can think of. If someone would weigh in and add, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Actually, `__class__` might be better if class decorators are used. It can help avoid infinite recursion. I'll add the full explanation later on.

Answer (score 1):

You're mistaking placing the namespace of the `Child` class within the `Parent` class with extending the `Child` class from the `Parent` class.

You can extend the `Child` class from `Parent` like so:

```
class Parent:
    a = 1

class Child(Parent):
    pass

>>> Child.a
1
```

Works the same with static methods.

Comment: It seems a little needlessly confusing to make `Parent` a "child class" of `Child`...

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree –– I mixed up the order. Updating now.

Comment: He does not wish to extend, the OP clearly wishes to nest a class, therefore although true, the answer is a little irrelevant.

Comment: @Bharel Given that he said "But since Child is nested, I can't call it using the conventional way." and then his code says `Child.bar()`, I interpreted that as wanting to extend

Comment: Might be, I'm not entirely sure. Nesting does have it's upside in terms of encapsulation. I might not be fond of it but then again I'm only here to answer the OP :-)

Answer (score 0):

When calling a static function in a nested class, you have to reference the parent as well.

```
Class Parent:

    Class Child:

        @staticmethod
        def foo():
             Parent.Child.bar()

        @staticmethod
        def bar():
            pass
```